# How to accept RequestBody of different class types dynamically

Tags: spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot . Writing rest api's 
where for the same api url , the request json structure varies 
Is there any way we can apply Factory design or some thing else

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/myservice/{type}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<?> myServiceApi(@PathVariable String type,
        @RequestBody SomeClass1 somereq) {
    // here based on type , the RequestBody can be either SomeClass1 or SomeClass2 
    // both the SomeClass1 and SomeClass2 has nothing in common .

}
```

The above code will work only if the request json is in SomeClass1 format , but i needed it to accept among {SomeClass1 , SomeClass2}

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could do this by passing the JSON as a String into your controller method and then mapping this to whichever object you expect to need:

```java
@PostMapping(value = "/myservice/{type}")
public ResponseEntity<?> myServiceApi(@PathVariable String type,
         @RequestBody String somereq) {
     ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    if (<something that indicates SomeClass1>) {
        SomeClass1 someClass1 = mapper.readValue(somereq, SomeClass1.class);
    } else if (<something that indicates SomeClass2>) {
        SomeClass2 someClass2 = mapper.readValue(somereq, SomeClass2.class);
    }
}
```

Although to be honest if you really are expecting bodies with completely different structures my advice would be to just make separate API calls for these.

Comment: Please add Clear explanation

Comment: I'm new to springboot, Should I have to create two DTO class one request to accept {name:some,userId:123} and if i'm accepting {name:some,userId:123,phone_no:99XXXX} or can I have one DTO class

Comment: @nitinsridar yes, you can have one DTO class in this case having all three fields, the phone_no for the first case will just be null